# dpkg: error processing openoffice4.0-debian-menus_4.0-9714_all.deb

Tags: dpkg, software-installation

Trying to install openoffice on Ubuntu 13.10 64bit. The install goes with out a hitch but the application does not show up in my GUI applications window. Is this because of desktop integration? When I try to install the desktop integrator I get this...

```
jacob@jacob-desktop:~/mydebs/en-US/DEBS/desktop-integration$ sudo dpkg -i *.deb(Reading database ... 172964 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking openoffice-debian-menus (from openoffice4.0-debian-menus_4.0-9714_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing openoffice4.0-debian-menus_4.0-9714_all.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package libreoffice-common 1:4.1.2~rc3-0ubuntu1
/usr/bin/gtk-update-icon-cache
gtk-update-icon-cache: Cache file created successfully.
/usr/bin/gtk-update-icon-cache
gtk-update-icon-cache: Cache file created successfully.
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openoffice4.0-debian-menus_4.0-9714_all.deb
```

Comment: If you don't mind which to use (they're pretty similar), prefer libreoffice, as it's in your distros repos anyway. Easy updates.

Comment: LibreOffice works _okay_ on my system, so I'm not comfortable messing with its installation at this stage. I just want to see if Open Office is better for what I'm trying to do. (Previous experience has shown that each package has advantages.) I therefore skipped deleting the symlinks, and after running the `dpkg -i *.deb` step, I was able to type `/opt/openoffice4/program/soffice` from the command line, and it seems to be working just fine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The installation doesn't go without a hitch:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openoffice4.0-debian-menus_4.0-9714_all.deb
```

This means there were error processing the packages, hence reading back:

```
dpkg: error processing openoffice4.0-debian-menus_4.0-9714_all.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package libreoffice-common 1:4.1.2~rc3-0ubuntu1
```

This means that you are trying to install OpenOffice.org while having LibreOffice installed. Eithe remove LibreOffice and continue the OpenOffice.org installation or forget about OpenOffice.org(**or go for `force-overwrite`**).

To do the first you must run:

```
sudo apt-get -f remove libreoffice-common
```

Then install OpenOffice.org.

#### Force Overwite

One way can be telling dpkg to force overwrite the exiting file. This command can be risky as in some cases, you may end up overwriting necessary files.**So use it at your own risk**.

To enable force-overwrite mode , pass `-o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite"` parameter to  `apt-get`.

`sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install <package-name>`

If you are trying to install a file using `dpkg` pass `--force-overwrite` to `dpkg` command.

`sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite <some_file.deb>`

Comment: Uhm... yeah... right *sips coffee*

Comment: Official OpenOffice [linux instructions](http://www.openoffice.org/download/common/instructions.html#linux) do not force to remove completely LibreOffice. Only to remove a pair of symlinks. I followed those instructions, yet now I'm facing this same issue.

Comment: @superjos I'm not sure what is the relationship between the file collision of the two packages and OO.o instructions. Explain yourself?

Comment: OpenO instructions say to not remove LibreOffice, just delete the symlinks that LibreO creates to "fake" the command `soffice`. So in theory they should be ok installed together. Then, while installing OpenO desktop-integration packages, I got the error mentioned in this question. The colliding file is one of those symlinks that OpenO instructions ask you to remove.

Comment: @superjos that's only the case for "manual" installations, which obviously isn't this case due the use of a package manager (dpkg) which tracks each package installed files and prevents collisions.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make that error *disappear* this is what I did:

1. follow OpenOffice instruction [here](http://www.openoffice.org/download/common/instructions.html#linux), in particular remove LibreOffice symlinks to "fake" `soffice` executable
2. when it's time for installing `desktop-integration` packages, force the install: `sudo dpkg --force-all -i *.deb`. I know this is usually discouraged ...

That of course overrides the error we are experiencing, but I already deleted the symlink manually anyway.