# Failed to satisfy dependencies (Broken Cache) when trying to install software

Tags: package-management, libreoffice, dependencies

I recently I installed mate on Ubuntu, which I believe messed things up. I get an error when trying to reinstall Google Chrome. It comes up with a pop-up saying ''broken dependencies, do you want to repair?'' I hit yes, and after a while, I get an error saying Package Operation failed. Here are the details:

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 272502 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.7-0ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:4.2.7-0ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.7-0ubuntu2_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package openoffice-debian-menus 4.1.1-9775
rmdir: failed to remove /var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove /var/lib/libreoffice/share/: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove /var/lib/libreoffice/program/: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove /var/lib/libreoffice: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove /var/lib/libreoffice: No such file or directory
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme (3.10.0-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.2.7-0ubuntu2_all.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-ogltrans:
 libreoffice-ogltrans depends on libreoffice-common; however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-ogltrans (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of ubuntu-mate-desktop:
 ubuntu-mate-desktop depends on libreoffice-ogltrans; however:
  Package libreoffice-ogltrans is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ubuntu-mate-desktop (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-core:
 libreoffice-core depends on libreoffice-common (>> 1:4.2.7); however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-uno:
 python3-uno depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.7-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-uno (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-math:
 libreoffice-math depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.7-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-math (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-impress:
 libreoffice-impress depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.7-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-impress (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-writer:
 libreoffice-writer depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.7-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-writer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-base-core:
 libreoffice-base-core depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:4.2.7-0ubuntu2); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
```

Comment: See  [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/382043/146791) answer.

Comment: I had tried to install Mate, which tried to install libreoffice while Openoffice was on the system. I cannot install or remove anything on the system.

Comment: Ok, Here is one of my answer. Try it.http://askubuntu.com/a/569475/146791

Comment: First tried to remove Libreoffice and got the same unmet dependencies issue. Same thing with open office. Should I just backup and reinstall ubuntu?