# How to install Open Office alongside Libre Office?

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice.org

I would like to install open office alongside Libre office (I do not want to get rid of LibreOffice) but whenever I try to install the desktop integration I get the following error:

```
(Reading database ... 206617 files and directories currently installed.)

Preparing to unpack .../openoffice4.1-debian-menus_4.1.1-9775_all.deb ...

Unpacking openoffice-debian-menus (4.1.1-9775) ...

dpkg: error processing archive /home/darkwraith/Setups/en-GB/DEBS/desktop-integration/openoffice4.1-debian-menus_4.1.1-9775_all.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package libreoffice-common 1:4.2.6.3-0ubuntu1

/usr/bin/gtk-update-icon-cache
gtk-update-icon-cache: Cache file created successfully.
/usr/bin/gtk-update-icon-cache

gtk-update-icon-cache: Cache file created successfully.

Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme (3.10.0-0ubuntu2) ...

Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...

Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...

Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...

Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...

Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...

Errors were encountered while processing:

 /home/darkwraith/Setups/en-GB/DEBS/desktop-integration/openoffice4.1-debian-menus_4.1.1-9775_all.deb
```

I would highly appreciate being told which steps to take to solve the above problem,thank you

Comment: Just follow the installation instructions: http://www.openoffice.org/download/common/instructions.html#linux-preinstall

Comment: I think this person wants to have both installed side-by-side, with desktop integration working in both (though I'm doubtful there is any desktop integration for open office as it's largely unused my most Linux users.)

Comment: Why? The one is a fork from the other. Why do you feel the need for both?

Comment: @DeanHowell: You're right - but as far as i see, none of the LibreOffice desktop entries are using the `/usr/bin/soffice` symlink. The all call `libreoffice` directly. So i assume LibreOffice will still work as usual even if the symlink to `/usr/bin/soffice` is "captured" by AOO.

Comment: @ ElderGeek I would like to try them both out...is there no difference?..Let me clarify my question though....Is there a way to install openoffice and still remain with libreoffice? and if so how?

Comment: did you make it in the end? I'm facing same issue now.

Answer (score 1):

I just posted an answer to the same issue in [this SO thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/683043/407424). Basically, before installing OpenOffice, one should remove symlinks to `soffice` that LibreOffice created, and then force install of `dekstop-integration` packages.

Comment: This worked thank you.